# Implementing a Write-Back Cache in Java

Tags: java, caching, soft-references

I trying to implement a write-back cache.  I'm trying to use soft referenes, but I'm having troubles performing the post-mortum write-back because the reference is cleared before it's added to the gcQueue and thus I don't have access to the referent object.

Solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Mapmaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

Example:

```
final ConcurrentMap<Long, Integer> cache = new MapMaker()
        .softValues().expiration(20,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .makeComputingMap(new Function<Long, Integer>() {
              @Override
            public Integer apply(Long arg0) {
                return null;
            }
            });
```

**SO Questions on MapMaker  :**

- [Use of Google-collections MapMaker ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737140/306855)
- [Using MapMaker to create a cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3210606/306855)

**Alternative option :**

Use Supplier class's [memoizeWithExpiration](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration(com.google.common.base.Supplier) which is also part of guava library.

Comment: I really can't see how it helps with the write-back.